# Error: Unknown command : --celler/bin

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying update ruby with rvm. When i use the following command i get this below error respectively. Please any one help me to get ride of it.

```
[prabhu@10.100.202.8 ~]$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p547.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:57: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR: 'Error: Unknown command: --cellar/bin' is not writable - it is required for Homebrew, try 'brew doctor' to fix it!
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Comment: Did you try to run `brew doctor`, like the error says?

Comment: i tried and got error as 'Unknown command: doctor'

Comment: I dont know what is the problem. but i uninstalled both rvm and brew then installed again it solved my problem.

Comment: rvm implode and then \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash fixed the problem for me.